# iPhone - Showing a modal view over a UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a UIImagePickerController, and while it's loading, I want to display a disclaimer in a modalView.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad 
{
    self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    self.picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
    self.picker.delegate = self;

    [self presentModalViewController:self.picker animated:NO];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];

    DisclaimerController* disclaimer = [[DisclaimerController alloc] init];  // Loads the Xib inside the init method
    UINavigationController* controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:disclaimer];
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

But it doesn't shows up.

And I don't want to dismiss the picker while the disclaimer is showing or show it later, because there are some treatments that takes some time and the time the user reads the disclaimer would prevent him to wait too long after closing the disclaimer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve it using an AlertView.

But if you prefer using your method maybe this will do the trick

Try this:

```
- (void) showModalDisclaimer {
        DisclaimerController* disclaimer = [[DisclaimerController alloc] init];  
        // Loads the Xib inside the init method
        UINavigationController* controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] 
                                          initWithRootViewController:disclaimer];
        [self.picker presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES]; 
        // notice self.picker
}

- (void) viewDidLoad 
{
    self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    self.picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
    self.picker.delegate = self;

    [self presentModalViewController:self.picker animated:NO];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO   
                       withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
    [self performSelector:@selector(showModalDisclaimer) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}
```

Comment: Thank you that works fine. Is the delay really needed ? Because if I replace the performSelector whith the showModalDisclaimer code, it also works.